# jplayer custom user-agent http header

Tags: javascript, jplayer

Is it possible to let [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) send a custom http user-agent header when requesting the mp3 file to play? (without changing the default user-agent for the browser globally)

something like

```
player.play({mp3: 'http://file.to.mp3', headers: {'User-Agent': 'test'}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible the bowser API is used for all requests.